# How to rotate QTVR image 360 degree in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I want to develope one iphone based application in which i want to rotate one image (type:QTVR) 360 degree. So, i can get the same behavior like street view in google map.

If anybody has done this then please share code snippet here or any useful url for any related article then please paste it in reply.

Any help is greatly appreciate.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Isn't a 360 degree rotation equivalent to doing nothing at all?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean you wanna "rotate" your point-of-view to "scroll" a panoramic image...

I'm using the software "Pano2vr"

It can export panoramas in HTML+javascript+css, so you can embed all the files in your project
and load it in a UIWebView

You can download the demo version to have a look here:

http://gardengnomesoftware.com/pano2vr.php

ciao, luca