# Does iphone support QuickTime VR?

Tags: iphone, quicktime

I have a 10MB QuickTime VR file and I was wondering if it would be possible to play it on an iPod/iPhone/iPad?

I've seen multiple messages about the subject around but nobody could give a straight answer if the iPhone fully support this format, partly support the format or doesn't support the format at all. If this format is supported, which OS version supports it?

Nope, I don't have an iPhone at my disposal to check this, unbelievable right?

Gilad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to use QTVR at all, it's never been developed by apple on iPhone
but there are some other similar object you can use.

take a look at my old answer to a similar:

[How to rotate QTVR image 360 degree in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091238/how-to-rotate-qtvr-image-360-degree-in-iphone/4775590#4775590)

Answer (score 1):

There's an app called iPano which views QTVRs, both panoramas and objects. It's ideal for viewing them and it let's you keep a collection of them on your phone. And it's really neat on the iPad too!