# Does iphone and ipad support QTVR (quicktime virtual reality)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm not succeeding in viewing QTVR objects on my web-view, if it is a QuickTime file it works, if it QuickTime virtual reality it does not work, should I add some properties to the web-view to support this features of virtual reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to use QTVR at all, it's never been developed by apple on iPhone but there are some other similar object you can use.

take a look at my old answer to a similar question:

[How to rotate QTVR image 360 degree in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091238/how-to-rotate-qtvr-image-360-degree-in-iphone/4775590#4775590)

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded the pano2vr and succeeded running the panoramic view by converting it to HTML page, but what makes me crazy is how come apple does not allow its own applications to run on its own products.

Comment: yeah, sure, i was guessing that too... but you know... apple doesn't develops QTVR software since many years, letting that "honor" to others...